# AD filter for ObjectClass user and group simultaneously

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I want to get from a given AD user all the description fields of its memberOf groups.

I am able to get all its memberOf groups with the following filter:

```
"(&(ObjectClass=user)(samAccountName=given_user)" memberOf
```

And I am also able to get the descriptions for all the groups with:

```
"(objectClass=group)" description
```

I have tried, with no success, to combine both filters with something like:

```
"(&(ObjectClass=user)(ObjectClass=group)(samAccountName=given_user)"
```

I think it would be possible to get the expected output with some kind of post-processing of the information given by both filters, but, Is it possible to achieve it directly with a filter?

Comment: No, the two filters cannot be combined. As you suspect, you'll need post-processing.

Comment: If you know a distinguished name of either, you might be able to combine them (but in that case the first query would be moot anyway)